# How to write html in Rails helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

How to write this html inside helper ?

```
 <tr style="color:red;">
        <td></td>
        <td><%= error_message_on "test", "test_message", :prepend_text => "Kem cho" %></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't write **this** code inside a helper method. Place it in a partial.

BTW if you really need html inside helper method you can use [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) helper.